# How do I pass a django auth token to view or serializer?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I am trying to work with a Token provided by 'rest_framework.authentication.TokenAuthentication',

I would like to either work with the token from the view or from the serializer. What method do I use to make a token viewable inside of my application?  Here is what i have tried only the current user returns. The 'auth' key returns none.

View

```
   class ReadProductView(generics.ListAPIView):
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]

    def get(self, request, format=None):
        content = {
                'auth': str(request.auth),
                'user': str(request.user),
        }
        return Response(content)
```

Settings...

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': [
        'rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication',
        'rest_framework.authentication.TokenAuthentication',  #Token authentication

    ],
}
```

Comment: Can you share the whole view and your DRF settings?

Comment: My settings are now included.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. I needed to add a library to my view to get access to the token.

the library:

from rest_framework.authtoken.models import Token

and I grabbed the token with a get method inside my class based view.

```
    def get(self, request, format=None):
        content = {
                'auth': str(Token.objects.get()),
                'user': str(request.user),
        }
        return Response(content)
```

Comment: This will not work if you have more than one token, and also just using `get` will not guarantee that the token you got is for the current user. The reason why you don't get the token is most likely because the authenticated user is taken from `SessionAuthentication`